# Script raising Exception as per python's logic but Test Case still passed in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am a new bee to Robot and having issue with my script execution part .

My case is failing correctly as per python's logic . However robot is still passing it . I am quite certain that i have missed out some thing on robot script end like some keyword maybe.

Any inputs and suggestion are more than welcome

I tried Run keywork if but i do not know how to use it . Please see both my python and robot code below

```
robot script:

*** Settings ***
Documentation       TC2
Library             exception
#Library           common_functions

*** Keywords ***

Run Keyword if 'FAIL' in $output

*** Test Cases ***
TEST CASE TWO
    validation
```

python code:

```
import os
import re


def validation():
    try:
        if 'loopback is up, line protocol is up' in open('1.txt').read():
            print("string found")

        else:
            print ("string not found")
            raise Exception("string not found")

    except:
        cleanup()

def cleanup():
    print("cleanup is in progress")


validation()
```

Expected result :

1. Python script showing : 
   string not found
   cleanup is in progress
2. Robot should show fail

Actual output :

1. Python script showing : 
   string not found
   cleanup is in progress
2. Robot script showing PASS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First guess, knowing nothing about the robot framework, but about to dive in): Your robot script is looking for `FAIL` in `$output`. Your output contains `string not found cleanup is in progress` (perhaps with different formatting, as you've printed twice without specifying to not print newlines). There is no `FAIL` in your output. Perhaps you meant to have

```
Run Keyword if 'string not found' in $output
```

in your robot script, or

```
print("FAIL: string not found")
```

in your validation code?

UPDATE: Now that I have spent some time with the documentation (they don't make it easy to learn to do something simple), I can say that Bence Kaulics answer is mostly correct, perhaps depending on what version you're running. For me, the test as shown in his answer fails with an `IndentationError` due to the `try` without `except`. Here's what I have that works (as in, fails for the expected reason, mostly):

.robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       TC2
Library             exception.py

*** Test Cases ***
TEST CASE TWO
    validation
```

exception.py:

```
def validation():
    try:
        if 'loopback is up, line protocol is up' in open('1.txt').read():
            result = 'string found'
        else:
            result = 'string not found'
            raise RuntimeError(result)
    except Exception as e:
        result = 'string not found'
        raise RuntimeError(result)
    finally:
        print(result)
        cleanup()


def cleanup():
    print("cleanup is in progress")
```

With the above, I get the output:

```
(robottestframework) ~/s/l/robottestframework> robot -L TRACE keyword_driven.robot  
==============================================================================
Keyword Driven :: TC2                                                         
==============================================================================
TEST CASE TWO                                                         | FAIL |
string not found
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Keyword Driven :: TC2                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Note that this changes the semantics of what you are testing: instead of checking the value of stdout, you are running a keyword imported from a library, and failing if there is an exception raised. IMO, that's a better way to go than checking stdout. However, if what you really need to do is check the value of stdout, you'll need something more like:

.robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       TC2
Library             Process
Suite Teardown      Terminate All Processes     kill=True

*** Test Cases ***
TEST CASE TWO
    ${result} =     Run Process     python      exception.py
    should not contain      ${result.stdout}        string not found
```

exception.py file:

```
def validation():
    result = ''
    try:
        if 'loopback is up, line protocol is up' in open('1.txt').read():
            result = 'string found'
        else:
            result = 'string not found'
            raise RuntimeError(result)
    except Exception as e:
        result = 'string not found'
    finally:
        print(result)
        cleanup()
    return result


def cleanup():
    print("cleanup is in progress")


validation()
```

With these changes, I get:

```
(robottestframework) ~/s/l/robottestframework> robot -L TRACE keyword_driven.robot  
==============================================================================
Keyword Driven :: TC2                                                         
==============================================================================
TEST CASE TWO                                                         | FAIL |
'string not found
cleanup is in progress' contains 'string not found'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Keyword Driven :: TC2                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: do i need to specify something in $output also , actually my output file is in location   /home/output.xml

Comment: do i need to specify something in $output also , actually my output file is in location /home/output.xml –  guys any input will be welcome i am using following now

Comment: Run Keyword if 'FAIL:string not found' in ${output} and i have also added this in my validation code

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm new to the robot framework as well, but I thought trying to answer your question would give me a good intro to it. I now have a project loaded with your example code. I'll let you know what I figure out.

Comment: Fantastic answer

Answer (score 3):

Do not catch the exception in your Python code, let that fail the robot execution. You can do the cleanup in the [test teardown section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown).

```
import os
import re


def validation():
    if 'loopback is up, line protocol is up' in open('1.txt').read():
        print("string found")

    else:
        print ("string not found")
        raise RuntimeError("string not found")


def cleanup():
    print("cleanup is in progress")
```

---

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       TC2
Library             exception

*** Test Cases ***
TEST CASE TWO
    validation
    [Teardown]    cleanup
```

Comment: Guys on second thoughts though can we do this via run keyword if

Comment: @Diwakar If you Python script would return a bool or a string, sure you could put that value into a `Run Keyword If` and execute the cleanup that way.